Tight upper bound on a ratio involving symmetric PSD matrices and Kronecker products
Let $\mathbf{A}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ ($i = 1, \dots, T$) be symmetric positive semidefinite (PSD) matrices. Define the quantity
$$
m = \frac{\lambda_{\max}\left(\sum_{i=1}^T \mathbf{A}_i^2\right)}{\lambda_{\max}\left(\sum_{i=1}^T \mathbf{A}_i \otimes \mathbf{A}_i\right)},
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product, and $\lambda_{\max}(\cdot)$ is the largest eigenvalue of a matrix.
Questions:

What is a tight upper bound on $m$?
Does this bound depend on $d$ and/or $T$, or is $m$ universally bounded by a constant independent of $d$ and $T$?

Observations:

It is straightforward to show that $m \geq 1$.
Numerical experiments suggest that $m$ is typically small. For example, I found cases where $m \approx 1.3$, but I couldn't construct any examples where $m > 1.3$.

I am particularly interested in whether $m$ is always bounded above by some constant that does not depend on $d$ or $T$. Any insights, references, or proof sketches would be greatly appreciated!

There is no upper for $m$ that is independent of $d$ and $T$. In fact, for a fixed $d$, the best upper bound that works for all $T$ is of order $\sqrt{d}$, and this is already tight for $T=d$.
The bound $m \leq \sqrt{d}$ is easy. Identifying $\mathbf{R}^d \otimes\mathbf{R}^d$ with the matrices of size $d$ with scalar product $\mathrm{Tr}(A^*B)$, we have
$$\lambda_{\max}(\sum_i A_i^2) = \sup_{\mathrm{Tr}(|X|)\leq 1} \mathrm{Tr}(\sum_i A_i^2 X) = \sup_{\mathrm{Tr}(|X|)\leq 1} \mathrm{Tr}(\sum_i A_i\otimes A_i X,\mathrm{id}_d) \leq \sqrt{d} \lambda_{max}(\sum_i A_i \otimes A_i),$$
because $(\mathrm{Tr}(X^*X)^2)^{\frac 1 2} \leq \mathrm{Tr}{|X|}$ and $(\mathrm{Tr}(\mathrm{id}_d^*\mathrm{id}_d)^2)^{\frac 1 2}=\sqrt{d}$.
For the converse inequality, use the following fact: if $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_T$ are unit vectors in a Hilbert space such that all pairwise scalar products are equal to some $c>0$, and if $P_i$ is the orthogonal projection on the line spanned by $\xi_i$ then $\|\sum_i P_i\| \simeq \max(1,cT)$ up to universal constants. This is because if $M=\sum_i P_i$, a straightforward computation gives that $M^2 = (1-c) M + (c^2 T^2 + (c-c^2)T)Q$ for $Q$ the rank one projection on the line spanned by $\sum_i \xi_i$.
Now, take such vectors $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_d \in \mathbf{R}^d$ with $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}$ and $A_i$ the orthogonal projection on $\xi_i$. By two applications of the fact (for $\xi_i$ and $c=1/\sqrt{d}$, and $\xi_i\otimes \xi_i$ and $c=1/d$ respectively), we get that $\|\sum_i A_i^2\|\simeq \max(1,c d) = \sqrt{d}$, whereas $\|\sum_i A_i \otimes A_i \|\simeq \max(1,c^2d)=1$.
Final comment: in the vocabulary of operator spaces, you are asking for the comparison of the operator spaces $\mathrm{OH}_n$ and $R_n \cap C_n$, in restriction to the positive-semidefinite coefficients. What I explain above is that that they are comparable with constant $\sqrt{n}$ and not better; this is certainly classical.

Regarding the converse inequality, are there other examples that achieve this bound? I’m particularly interested in cases where the orthogonal projections have ranks on the order of almost $d$. Additionally, could you point me to any textbooks or papers where this result or related examples are discussed?
